# Matlab illustration for Gaussian Mixture Model using contour3 or anything

Tags: matlab, gaussian

I have fitted a 3D data set (x1, x2,x3) using Gaussian Mixture Model. Now I have the pdf as well. How can I illustrate this fitting in matlab? I was trying to use contour3, but it requires nXm matrix and my data are all 40000x1. 
For example,

```
X1=[254
254
255
254
254
252
254
253
254
255
254
254
254
253
254
]
X2=[255
254
254
254
255
254
255
255
253
255
254
255
253
254
255
]
X3=[250
242
249
244
241
249
239
234
249
243
246
237
248
246
247
]

NPixel=90000;

NOfComponents=7;

X=[X1,X2,X3];

obj = gmdistribution.fit(X,NOfComponents,'Options',options);
```

All the data are on the RGB space from 1-255. It is similar as we illustrate a 3D gaussian problem in 3D surface.

Can any expert help here?
Thanks

Comment: Post some code with a specific (small) example

Comment: I have already added an example, plz check.Thanks

Comment: Your variable `options` is undefined

Comment: It is defined:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.fit.html
My question is how to illustrate a 3D Gaussian in Matlab using contour.

Comment: @KaMu: Luis Mendo's question is: what value of `option` did you use to run the fit? If you want us to help you, you should provide us with as much as possible to work with.

Comment: More to the point: You say you have the pdf, so you can evaluate it on a 3d grid and then use `contour3`, right? Also, `contour3` does not work on a 2d matrix as you write, but on a 3d matrix.

Comment: It is exactly like the one on the link provided, it has no relation to my question thats why I didnt included it. 
options = statset('Display','final','MaxIter',300); @A. Donda contour3 works by using 3 matrix each has to be more than 1D thats why  I am totally confused here. Can u give an example that works with 3D Gaussian?

Comment: Ah, you're right, `contour3` just plots contours at different heights, but those are still contours of a 2d matrix. My mistake. Ok, so what you can try is to compute contours of the single 2d slices of your 3d pdf matrix. Calculate them with `contourc` and then plot them at different heights. Or alternatively, try `isosurface`.